# Caught UnicodeEncodeError while rendering: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 4-5: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: mysql, django, unicode, utf-8, django-admin

Hello I live in Poland so I have to deal with letters like łóźć etc. When I try to add, in admin pannel, text like "Zespół Szkół" I get  error like this:

> Caught UnicodeEncodeError while rendering: 'ascii' codec can't encode
>   characters in position 4-5: ordinal not in range(128)

I seen on Stackoverflow page many of similar problem but I don't have any idea how to solve my.

My Databse is **MySQL**

Unicode collection for my db: **utf8_unicode_ci**

My **models.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models
import codecs

...    

class experience(models.Model):
    dateStart = models.DateField()
    dateEnd = models.DateField()
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.company.decode('utf8')    

...
```

Traceback

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://vm:8000/admin/mycv/experience/

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.6.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'cv.mycv']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html, error at line 97
   Caught UnicodeEncodeError while rendering: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 4-5: ordinal not in range(128)
   87 :         {% endif %}


   88 :       {% endblock %}


   89 : 


   90 :       <form id="changelist-form" action="" method="post"{% if cl.formset.is_multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %}>{% csrf_token %}


   91 :       {% if cl.formset %}


   92 :         <div>{{ cl.formset.management_form }}</div>


   93 :       {% endif %}


   94 : 


   95 :       {% block result_list %}


   96 :           {% if action_form and actions_on_top and cl.full_result_count %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}


   97 :            {% result_list cl %} 


   98 :           {% if action_form and actions_on_bottom and cl.full_result_count %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}


   99 :       {% endblock %}


   100 :       {% block pagination %}{% pagination cl %}{% endblock %}


   101 :       </form>


   102 :     </div>


   103 :   </div>


   104 : {% endblock %}


   105 : 

Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  307.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  93.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  79.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  197.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  28.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  93.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  24.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changelist_view
  1179.         ], context, context_instance=context_instance)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
  20.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  188.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  123.             return self._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  117.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  127.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  117.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  127.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  117.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  64.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  64.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  921.                     dict = func(*args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py" in result_list
  232.             'results': list(results(cl))}
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py" in results
  217.             yield ResultList(None, items_for_result(cl, res, None))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py" in __init__
  209.         super(ResultList, self).__init__(*items)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py" in items_for_result
  137.             f, attr, value = lookup_field(field_name, result, cl.model_admin)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/util.py" in lookup_field
  218.                 value = attr()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in __str__
  377.             return force_unicode(self).encode('utf-8')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/encoding.py" in force_unicode
  71.                 s = unicode(s)
File "/home/lechu/apps/cv/../cv/mycv/models.py" in __unicode__
  31.         return self.company.decode('utf8')    
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/encodings/utf_8.py" in decode
  16.     return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/mycv/experience/
Exception Value: Caught UnicodeEncodeError while rendering: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 4-5: ordinal not in range(128)




   104 : {% endblock %}


   105 : 

Traceback:
File
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `__unicode__` method is unfortunately nonsense.

`decode` is for converting bytestrings to unicode, but `self.company` is *already* unicode. So calling `decode('utf-8')` on it means that Python has to implicitly encode it to a bytestring first, which it does by the default `ascii` encoding - which will fail as soon as you have any accented characters.

I don't know what you were trying to do with that method, but `__unicode__` methods should always return unicode. Just `return self.company` is the correct thing to do here.